# Dimension analysis and explaining the $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

> Reference of this post ([page no 6 from equation 39](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525))
>
> The time averaged total energy, $\bar E$, has the following
>    $\varepsilon$ expansion in $D$ dimension: \begin{equation}
> \bar{E}=\varepsilon^{2-D}\frac{E_0}{2\lambda}+ \varepsilon^{4-D}E_1\,,
>  \quad {\rm where}\quad E_0=\int d^{D}\zeta\,S^2\,, \tag{1}
>  \end{equation} In $D=2$ $\bar E$ tends to a constant, and for $D<2$ it
>   goes to zero as $\varepsilon\to 0$. This also implies that the core
>   energy of a QB in dimensions $D>2$ should exhibit a minimum for some
>   frequency $\omega_{\rm m}$. In fact, from Eq.1 one immediately finds
>   \begin{equation} \omega_{\rm m}^2=1-\varepsilon_{\rm m}^2=
> > 1-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\frac{(D-2)E_0}{(4-D)E_1}\,. \end{equation} The
>   above result can only be taken as an indication of the minimum even if
>   $\varepsilon_{\rm m}\ll1$. The numerical values of $E_0$ and $E_1$
>   will be given for the fundamental solutions in $D=2$ and $D=3$ in case
>   of spherical symmetry in Section iii.

The problem I got from the above expresson is, how $D<2$ as as $\varepsilon\to 0$? 
and how will I explain the limit of dimension of this equation?  I mean after what valoue of D the above equation would notwork.

Please ask if any thing needed to explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I correctly understood the question, the answer is that $D$ is a fixed number not depending on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: But for different D, the value of $\varepsilon$ changes. Can you check the article I attached please? And $D$ refers here number of dimensions.

Comment: $D$ is fixed and $\varepsilon$ is an argument of the function. For different values of $D$ the function in question has different behavior, in particular when $\varepsilon\to0$. That seems to be all they are saying.